# How can I find the number of votes I gave on questions?

Tags: support, voting

How can I find the number of votes I gave on questions?
I find the total number of votes, the number of up/down votes, etc. But I can't find the votes only on questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's on your user page, at the bottom right, under the badges section. Here it is for your profile on main:

[image]

Comment: thanks, should have just searched more!